# RAMDiskVE keeps causing computer to freeze

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I found this in the Event Viewer logs:

The description for Event ID 11 from source RAMDiskVE cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

Which doesn't say much. The details don't reveal much more:

Failed to read configuration information from registry. 
   0000000002002C00000000000B0007C0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

So my question is, what is RAMDiskVE and what device is it for? Basically I'm trying to rule out hardware but I have no idea what's failing...

Comment: I'm reading that this may be due to Acronis. And I'm seeing Acronis logs around the same time of the failure...

Answer (score 0):

Having done more research, I believe the issue may actually lie with Acronis. I've since uninstalled the application and I've had no further issues so far...